# Getting the first of a GROUP BY clause in SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement single-column regionalization for a Rails application and I'm running into some major headaches with a complex SQL need. For this system, a region can be represented by a country code (e.g. `us`) a continent code that is uppercase (e.g. `NA`) or it can be `NULL` indicating the "default" information. I need to group these items by some relevant information such as a foreign key (we'll call it `external_id`).

Given a country and its continent, I need to be able to select only the **most specific** region available. So if records exist with the country code, I select them. If, not I want a records with the continent code. If not that, I want records with a `NULL` code so I can receive the default values.

So far I've figured that I may be able to use a generated `CASE` statement to get an arbitrary sort order. Something like this:

```
SELECT *, CASE region 
            WHEN 'us' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'NA' THEN 2 
            ELSE 3 
          END AS region_sort 
          FROM my_table 
          WHERE region IN ('us','NA') OR region IS NULL 
          GROUP BY external_id 
          ORDER BY region_sort
```

The problem is that without an aggregate function the actual data returned by the `GROUP BY` for a given row seems to be untameable. How can I massage this query to make it return only the **first record** of the `region_sort` ordered groups?

Comment: Do you want an aggregate by region or the first row in each region or something else?

Comment: I want one result per external_id (this could be many results total) that is the most specific of the regions available for that external_id. So if there's two models with external_id=3, I only want the one that's 'us' if there's both 'us' and NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first record or only the first **group** of records?  It's not even clear from what you've written whether there is more than one record or not.

In any case, it seems you are bending over backwards to do this in one query, but the database structure is not optimized for this.  If there's just 3 levels and you want the most specific, why not just:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE region = 'us' GROUP BY external_id
```

If that returns something then you, stop, otherwise you run 1 or 2 more queries conditionally.

I could be wrong, but my instinct says that will yield much better overall performance, though I suppose it depends on the particulars of your DB.

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit of a mess trying to explain this because it's complicated to begin with. The problem is I expect there could be valid results for all three levels of specificity, i.e. some that have a 'us' region, some that have 'NA' and some that have NULL. I want to do it in one query because otherwise I have to manually composite them which is definitely not ideal.